# CloudFront distribution comment maximum length?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the Java SDK 2 to create an AWS CloudFront distribution, but it failed telling me the comment I provided was too long. But it didn't say how long it could be. Moreover I was able to provide a much longer comment for a Route 53 hosted zone with no problem.

What is the maximum length of a comment for a CloudFront distribution? Where is this documented?

*Update:* After some experimentation, it seems the comment is allowed to be a little over 120 characters. I didn't have time to keep testing and close in on the exact number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed [Bug #1468](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1468) for the [AWS Java SDK2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) project on GitHub. Someone [responded](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1468#issuecomment-540810759) saying that the maximum length of an AWS CloudFront distribution comment is likely `128` characters, and that they will request the documentation team specify this somewhere.